Return conditional excel value
I have 2 Sheets:
Sheet1



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H




2
Particulars








3
1
EMP   ID




3


4

*   Annual / Stagnation Increment date-->




01.11.2022


5

*   Annual / Stagnation Increment date-->




01.06.2023


6

*   Annual / Stagnation Increment date-->




01.11.2023


7

*   Annual / Stagnation Increment date-->







8

*   Retired / Relived w.e.f 00-00-000








Sheet2



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J




3
EMP ID
EMP   NAME
ANNUAL   INCREMENT DATE
ANNUAL   INCREMENT      AMOUNT
ADVANCE   INCREMENT TYPE
ADVANCE   INCREMENT DATE
ADVANCE   INCREMENT AMOUNT
ANNUAL   INCREMENT DATE
ANNUAL   INCREMENT      AMOUNT


4
1
ABHIMANYU
01.12.2022
1490







5
2
AJIT
01.11.2022
1490



01.11.2023
1730


6
3
KARMVIR
01.11.2022
1490
(CPCB)-Level   II
01.06.2023
1490
01.11.2023
1730


7
4
SUNNY
01.11.2022
1490
(CPCB)-Level   II
01.06.2023
1490
01.11.2023
1730


8
5
AMAR
01.11.2022
1490
(CPCB)-Level   II
01.06.2023
1730
01.11.2023
1730


9
6
PUSPRAJ
01.11.2022
1490



01.11.2023
1490


10
7
SHAILESH
01.11.2022
1490
(CPCB)-Level   I
01.07.2023
1490
01.11.2023
1490


11
8
GOVINDA
01.11.2022
1490



01.11.2023
1730


12
9
AVINASH
01.11.2022
1490
(CPCB)-Level   I
01.07.2023
1490
01.11.2023
1490


13
10
PRIYA
01.11.2022
1490



01.11.2023
1730


14
11
NUPUR
01.11.2022
1490



01.11.2023
1730


15
12
ABHISHEK
01.11.2022
1490
(CPCB)-Level   II
01.06.2023
1490
01.11.2023
1730



I want to be able to lookup date values from column D, G & I in Sheet2 where the EMP ID # in column B from Sheet2 equal the ID # in Sheet1 cell H3, and list the date values (excluding blanks)
So for EMP ID 3 expected results are:
01.11.2022
01.06.2023
01.11.2023

Being the column D, G & I values in row 6 of Sheet2 (the row showing EMP ID 3)
For EMP ID 2 expected results are:
01.11.2022
01.11.2023

Being the column D, G & I values in row 5 of Sheet2 (the row showing EMP ID 2). Since G5 is empty/blank, it's excluded from the result.
You can find a link to the file below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wS_AY5MRgkIcuYPMrZEs_6w5K-hXY2mG/edit?usp=drivesdk&ouid=100182063372689680717&rtpof=true&sd=true
I try nested IF with VLOOKUP. It returns 1st non-blank value but not fffff. when I try to fill next row I49, I cant get 2nd non-blank cell value in I49.

Your explanation refers to a different part of the sheet(s) than posted. Make sure we can reproduce an answer from data you post. You can post tables as data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables (by editing your question).

name of sheets are interchanged rest is correct.

Well, then I'd advise to search by ID, not name. Still your data (images) don't reflect something reproducable. The example name/ID is not listed, neither is your example 2nd output fffff.

=let(f,filter(CHOOSECOLS(Sheet2!D4:J15,1,4,6),Sheet2!B4:B15=H3),tocol(filter(f,len(f))))
This filters out the row # of the corresponding ID and returns only the date columns containing data.

Here is another alternative way of accomplishing the output, MS365 Exclusive:
=TOCOL(FILTER(CHOOSEROWS(Sheet2!D4:I15,XMATCH(H3,Sheet2!B4:B15)),{1,0,0,1,0,1}),1)



Using XMATCH() get the position of the EMP ID in the Sheet 1
Using CHOOSEROWS()get the specific row.
Using FILTER() to grab specific columns.
Finally, using TOCOL() to ignore any blanks and turning into single column array.


Or, You could use VLOOKUP() as well:
=TOCOL(VLOOKUP(H3,Sheet2!B4:J15,{3,6,8},0),1)



I thought TOCOL(,1) didn't work, but that's because I used it on FILTER, not returning a range, but an array. It works very well on VLOOKUP. I love that answer.

@P.b Sir, thought you are not there so deleted the comment. Yes, using VLOOKUP() was pretty straight forward realized later.
